# npm very slow, 'npm-audit-fix --force' leaves vulnerabilities.. not sure what i have to fix

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, create-react-app

i don't know when it started, but everytime i use NPM it seems to have issues. It's working very slow, it often gets stuck, and if it does, it can be unstuck by pressing CTRL-C, commands like `create-react-app`, that used to run in around 30s now need around 5m. And when i afterwards run `npm-audit-fix --force`, it alternates between having the result `6 high severity vulnerabilitie`s and `78 vulnerabilities (13 low, 19 moderate, 42 high, 4 critical)` and tells me to run `npm audit fix` / `npm-audit-fix --force` again

I already tried deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, and run `npm install` again, but the result stayed the same.

I have absolutely no clue whats happening and where to fix it. I'm thankful for any tip! Thanks in advance.

Additional Info:
Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19045 Build 19045
Using Powershell in Admin-Mode to run the commands
Powershell Version 5.1.19041.2673
Powershell BuildVersion 10.0.19041.2673
Powershell CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000
NVM Version 1.1.10
NPM Version 8.11.0
Node Version 17.9.1

Hardware:
AMD Ryzen 7 2700X
RTX 3060 12gb
DDR4 16gb (1x, SingleChannel)
Windows and the Project is running on a WDS200T2B0B WD Blue 2TB 3D NAND Internal SSD M.2

Comment: Any idea what changed (or didn't change) from when code ran quicker?

Comment: sadly, no - im absolutely uncertain what couldve changed.. as far as i remember, the only thing that changed in my system is that i installed PCSX2 (PS2 Emulator) and VB-Cable (Virtual Audio Cable), but i think this has nothing to do with it.. i also uninstalled both, just to be sure, no changes (and i did restarts and i also tried reverting to a system recreation point after uninstall didnt have any effect)

Comment: When was last time it worked right?

Comment: i can not tell for sure.. 2 weeks ago , but im not completely sure.. im working mostly on my mac, and didnt work on my windows machine for a while...

any ideas for general trouble shooting ideas that are faster than doing a fresh win install? thats my only idea right now,...

Comment: Check for recent windows updates.  I would also run antivirus tool to check for issues.  While running you may want to view event viewer to see if anything is using large amount of processing speed.  I would also try defrag you hard drive.